# Survey Monkey- Responses data consolidation

Tags: csv, export, surveymonkey, consolidation, python-responses

I have created 116 surveys under my account. All the surveys have 50 similar questions with different images presented. I wanted to know if there is a way to export the responses of all the surveys to a single CSV file.

Comment: You should consider looking at the SurveyMonkey docs, because this is a third party

Comment: Assuming you have a way to identify the similar questions as being "the same" question, then all the tools are available to do that with the SurveyMonkey API (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/)

Comment: The real problem will be the question names in the exported csv files. You could use python pandas or R `dplyr` to `bind_rows` quite easily, if they headers of the csv files were equal.